# MySQL enforce uniqueness across two columns?

Tags: mysql

I want to store three columns in a database, prohibiting duplicate entries:

( 'Name' , 'Location' , 'Data' )

Here's what I'm doing so far, but it only enforces uniqueness on Name.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SomeStuff (
Name VARCHAR(200),
Location VARCHAR(200),
Data LONGTEXT,
UNIQUE INDEX (Name)
)
```

What I want to do is enforce unique combinations of Name and Location.  i.e. if I have these entries to store, I want that all to be valid:

```
Toothbrush , Ohio , (DATA)
Bacon , Ohio , (DATA)
Sandwich , Kansas , (DATA)
Sandwich , Ohio , (DATA)
Bacon , Kansas , (DATA)
```

However, if I try to store this entry, I want that to be invalid:

```
Bacon , Ohio , (DIFFERENT_DATA)    <--Database won't allow this
```

How do I structure a table definition to do that?

I'm periodically updating the (DATA) column using a line like this:

```
REPLACE INTO LicenseData (Name, Location, Data)
VALUES ( arg , arg , arg )
```

This was working before I had to keep track of Location, so right now I cannot store both `( Sandwich , Kansas )` and `( Sandwich , Ohio )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know T-SQL better than MySql, but maybe you can do this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SomeStuff (
Name VARCHAR(200),
Location VARCHAR(200),
Data LONGTEXT,
UNIQUE INDEX (Name, Location)
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I didn't really want to give a name to the combined index (`UNIQUE INDEX Foofoo (Name,Location)`) so it's great that's not necessary.  I found out though that I can't use a length of 200 on Name and Location though. The combined index has to be under 1000 bytes, and each char is more than one byte so it didn't fit.  VARCHAR(100) works fine for me though.  (The number of elements in the DB is small.)

Answer (score 3):

You should add a **unique key** for the pair `Name, Location`, e.g. [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Defining_unique_keys).

Comment: Another link too :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Yay. In MS Access you can click on "Indexes" and select multiple columns. I think that corresponds to the "unique" constraint, though I never checked the SQL.

Comment: Is the syntax `unique index (Name,Location)`? I see no actual examples and the syntax in that link looks different that what I've been looking up for MySQL, and I'm new to SQL.

Comment: @AR: Oh, just an index isn't enough, it has to be unique. You can index all sorts of stuff, but the constraint is separate.

Comment: @Brian: `ALTER TABLE SomeStuff ADD CONSTRAINT MyUniqueKey UNIQUE(Name, Location);`, or something like that.